# Scheduled posts are being published immediately

Tags: scheduled-posts

I do have the same issue as in [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274576/all-wordpress-scheduled-posts-are-being-published-immediately). Since I can't leave a comment and so I post another new topic for help. Does anybody else can solve it? I come across the same issue suddenly. I haven't tried to add 'post_status' => 'publish' to arg as it is not a workable way for me since I do not know when and how many of my user writing a "future" post. I can't teach them to add that to arg one by one for everytime when do making a scheduled post, they are a typical end user, no coding. Besides, it should be a default feature that should be working without extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server time and check time from WordPress **Settings >> General** and check your time zone there.

Install the [Health Check plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/), run it, and check what it says about **WP-Cron**.

Remove this `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` code from the wp-config.php file. 
Also, Contact your hosting provider regarding this issue :)

Comment: Thanks. I installed the health check plugin but I couldn't find any part for wp-cron. I thought it is because I just checking in one of the subsite, but when I activate in network level, I can't even find the health check info page. BTW, I quite sure the cron task in my site is working fine and the problem is not the scheduled post not appear on scheduled time and it show instantly. So should I still focus on cron issue? 
And the time zone setting is correct too. 
Please advise, thanks a lot.

Comment: can you try after disabling all activated plugins?

Comment: ok thanks. Found one of our plugins causing the scheduled post problem. =)

Comment: aah !, that great :)

Comment: @Anfield Which plugin?